# Execute script from plain HTML in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm fetching a plain HTML widget which contains a script tags from remote API to vuex store.
To properly render this widget scripts needs to be executed.
Inside vue component I'm doing it this way:

```
<div v-html="widget" id="widget-container"></div>


computed: mapGetters(["widget"]), // getter returns string of plain HTML
    methods: {
        renderWidget () {
            let container = document.getElementById("widget-container")
            let scriptsTags = container.getElementsByTagName("script")
                for (let i = 0; i < scriptsTags.length; i++) {
                    let parentNode = scriptsTags[i].parentNode
                    let newScriptTag = document.createElement("script")
                    newScriptTag.type = "text/javascript"
                    newScriptTag.text = scriptsTags[i].text
                    parentNode.removeChild(scriptsTags[i])
                    parentNode.appendChild(newScriptTag)
                }
            },
        }
```

It works perfectly if I assign this method to button click event or else, but not on

```
mounted () { 
    this.renderWidget()
}
```

hook. Nothing happens.

So how should I execute scripts after fetching?

Comment: The time you calling the rederWidget() -method the widget was not fetched yet. You can use a watcher though: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers ... besides that the way you importing the script is kind of strange ... never see that before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`widget` value isn't available on mount. Script execution can be triggered when a widget is already available in DOM, either with a watcher or `updated` hook:

```
  watch: {
    widget(widgetHtml) {
      if (!widgetHtml)
        return;

      this.$nextTick(this.renderWidget);
    }
  }
```

Notice that this way scripts can be evaluated multiple times.